# Haproxy backend unique server request

Tags: haproxy

I have the following set haproxy receives tcp/ssl connection does the ssl removal and should forward the tcp request to a single backend server(i can only have a single server). Its working however i am having a performance issue because the haproxy maintains a the connection to the final server i cannot have the full performance of that server. it is possible to configure the haproxy so that every server connection is unique?

Comment: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-max-keep-alive-queue perhaps you want to set a low limit to limit reuse as noted in the example below the definition.

Comment: I thought that i had gone through all of the configuration options.. need to pay extra attention next  time. Thanks for your suggestion it improve marginally only. I saw other options as making haproxy a transparent proxy, this however imply configuring iptables, that wold increase failure points. or using hitch tls. my solution was to move the ssl to the server side, removing haproxy from the overall solution.